# How to add a class to an element when thead table was click in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a class **Open** to **li** element on class **Menus** when user click on **thead tr th** of my table as below.

This is my table

```
<div><ul>
 <li class="menus">
    <a></a>
    <ul><li>
     <table id="tableid ">
        <thead>
          <tr><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
                <td></td>
                <td id="type1">types1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td id="types2">types2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td></td>
                <td id="type1">types3</td>
                <td></td>
                <td id="types2">types4</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li></ul></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click','#tableid thead tr th', function(){
    var parents = $(this).prevAll().find('li')
    console.log(parents)

});
```

Comment: The HTML structure is invalid. `div` cannot be part of `ul` and `tbody`.... ummm where is `<table>`?

Comment: use accordion instead ... if I am understood what you trying to do

Comment: your table creation syntax is incorrect. please update your code

Answer (score 2):

Use `.parents`and `.addClass`

```
$(document).on('click','#tableid thead tr th', function(){
    var parents = $(this).parents('li.menus').addClass('open')
    console.log(parents)
});
```

Comment: I have used this  var parents = $(this).offsetParent().offsetParent().offsetParent(); although it work but it should better or should we used loop to find it or what

Comment: there is no use to use loop in it and your code might work perfect but as its lengthy and not necessary we should choose `.parents`